# SEGV_ACCERR and crash app sometime on NSOperation when do [self.managedObjectContext save:&error]

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperation

I have a problem that I can't understand how to handle because does not happen logically.

I have some `NSOperation`s that run concurrently. For example,

```
- (void)main
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {        
        AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [self.managedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
        [self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [appController persistentStoreCoordinator]];

        NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
        [nc addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                 object:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                       entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K != %@",@"number1",[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects) {

            //Do Something with managed object then save        
            NSError *error = nil;
            //[episode release];
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
                // You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful
                // during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert
                // panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
                //
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AppDelegate *appController = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appController managedObjectContext];

    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) 
                              withObject:notification
                           waitUntilDone:YES];  
}
```

This is my typical `NSOperation`, that works concurrently and update my object in the core data, and sometime with no explanation the app crash and I receive that error on this line:

```
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
```

In my crash reports, so my question is, there is a way to prevent the app crash and fix the error? Can I can use a `@syncronized` when I perform `save`? Is this due to different threads and different objects? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the code you use to merge changes in the app delegate.

So, within `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` register for the notification.

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
[nc addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
           name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
         object:nil]; // set nil here
```

Then, always within the app delegate create your `mergesChanges:` method. Here you need to be sure that the notification runs on the main thread and the context you received the notification is different from the main one.

```
- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([notification object] == [self managedObjectContext])
        return;

    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChanges:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) 
                              withObject:notification
                           waitUntilDone:YES];  
}
```

P.S. Here you are using a non-concurrent `NSOperation` that, if inserted into a `NSOperationQueue`, will run in a concurrent manner (the queue, by means of GCD will manage this for you).

Comment: thank you for the answers, so i doesn't need to change my nsoperation like @Joel sad? override the start method and not the main method like i did?

Comment: If you use a `NSOperationQueue`, it's not needed. @Piero take a look also at [importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/22/importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data/). Using a concurrent operations (achieved by overriding the `start` method) is not useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a concurrent operation. And your `mergeChanges` notification will probably never get called because as soon as the main method finishes the operation will be deallocated (which will probably be before the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` selector gets executed).

If you want a concurrent operation that sticks around until you are done with it, you need to override the `start` method and `isConcurrent` method. You are probably getting this error because your `NSError` or selector are going out of scope before completing. I suggest reading this article to understand how concurrent vs. non-concurrent operations work:

Please check [Concurrent Operations Demystified](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/) by Dave Dribin for further details.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and i have to register to this notification [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
             object:self.managedObjectContext]; and insert this method, or i doens't need it anymore?

Comment: There is no need to create a concurrent operation here. I think @Piero   uses operations added to a queue.

Comment: If you want a concurrent operation to work, then you need to make the changes I suggested so the operation doesn't terminate before the notification is received. You could also move the selector out of the operation and shunt it over to the main thread as @flexaddicted suggests.